# How should I organize the words of a sentence for better outputs/maintenance and performance?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, algorithms

Having this sentence (consider many sentences in the future)

> David Henderson Houston patented the first roll film for cameras in
>   1881.

I can make questions like 

1. Who patented the roll film?

2. When was the first roll film for cameras patented?

3. What did David Houston patent (in 1881)?

The answer will return some or all of the sentence above in a format of answering the who, when and what.

My question (and what I am trying to achieve) is to separate this sentence in such a way that I can save it in a DB, smartly and efficiently.

I thought of editing this sentence leaving only the main keywords/facts; let's say `David Houston patented the roll film in 1881.`

After this, I thought I have to organize the words. So a solution may be to create tables for nouns, verbs, adjectives... separating the sentence in the correct table. Every word will have its unique ID.

In the table `answers`, the answer will be saved in a form like 2,23,64,4 every ID is a word... and with some agorithm and sql magic (this is not my point now) it will return the `David Houston patented the roll film in 1881` on the question `who`.

What do you think of my thinking of separating the sentences like I wrote above? What are your thoughts on how I should organize the words to access them through a database? Am I entirely off the correct path?

Comment: Your question basically comes down to: "How do I design an ontology?" You might want to read [some](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.108.7452&rep=rep1&type=pdf) of the existing [papers](http://protege.stanford.edu/publications/ontology_development/ontology101-noy-mcguinness.html) on the [subject](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.131.9912&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: The first thing you want to do is talk to those IBM guys who designed Watson, they rule at this sort of thing..  They wrote all that stuff in Java right?

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Language_Toolkit

Comment: @MikeChristensen I dont think that there will be anything more powerfull than Watson ever!

Comment: You're asking a very big question. There's a vast literature on natural language processing. You need to start getting books on the subject and reading them. This isn't something to attempt in an afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

I think before you consider a way to store it, you must decide on a consistent sentence structure.
With your current example (removing all prepositions)
David Houston patented the roll film in 1881.
All your sentences must follow this format: 
Name | Action | Object | When 
If this is the case then you can store data in just those 4 fields.  If you want to store answers as numbers then you would need a 5 tables, 1 for each Name, Action, Object, Date (each with 2 fields, an ID number and the description) and a 5th table to tie them all together like your | 2 | 23 | 64 | 4 | example.  If you have a lot of data this would be the best way to go, especially if David Houston also did hundreds or thousands other things that you would like to store. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually parse each sentence into its grammatical parts, as you would do in a [sentence diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_diagram).

Then you can make questions by removing one or more parts.

For example, you can remove the subject of the sentence, and replace it with "Who" or "What".

Or, you could remove the predicate, and ask: "What did (subject) do?"